# Closed proposals on Area 51 have a link to a 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, 404-not-found

For the two [closed](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6607/artificial-intelligence) [proposals](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets) on Area 51, there is a sidebar box that says:

> You could try [proposing a variation of
>   this site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create) that you think will have a
>   better chance.

The creation page now requires that you add a `category` parameter in the URL, which should be the category that the closed proposal was listed under. However, the existing link omits this parameter and links to a 404.

Obviously, this is not too much of a concern presently with only two closed sites, but it should be a fairly trivial fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The broken links on the failed-proposal pages, along with a couple other hard-to-find broken create-proposal links, are fixed now. Thanks.